# Каким образом здесь такой плавный скролл?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

понравился плавный скролл на сайте https://www.carineroitfeld.com/en
Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом сделали, просмотрел более 3 страниц Google в поисках подходящего но ничего
Из более похожих это scroll-behavior: smooth
Но все же не так медленно как сайте CarineRoitfeld

Comment: я же скидывал пример плавного скролла в двух вариантах - почему не подошло ?

Comment: Не работают должным образом

Comment: поясни что это значит - не работает должным образом

Comment: Мне кажется под фразой "должным образом" скрывается параллакс эффекты, которые есть на том сайте. Там вот, @Danielqwaqwaqwa, не один скролл не даст вам их на пустом месте, это всё нужно прорабатывать с вашей вёрсткой и вашей фантазией.

Comment: там используется код с requestAnimationFrames и доскролы делаются руками в коде